# Display a message after user selects a button in bot chat window

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have a conversation flow in the bot such that upon receiving user message, we display a relevant answer from QnAMaker and then ask user to select a category.
In the bot chat window, after user selects a button, I should be able to display YOU HAVE SELECTED XYZ and then continue with the flow. The existing flow displays the selected option since I am using 'imback' in cardactions.

Code:

```
private List<CardAction> CreateButtons(out List<string> ids)
{
    var ds = new List<string> { "operating group", "geo", "technology", "themes" };

    ids = new List<string>();

    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
    foreach (var keyword in ds)
    {
        ids.Add(keyword);
        CardAction CardButton = new CardAction()
        {                    
            Type = "imBack",
            Title = keyword,
            Value = keyword
        };
        cardButtons.Add(CardButton);
    }
    return cardButtons;
}
```

INVOKING:

```
var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();               

List<string> ids = new List<string>();
List<CardAction> cardButtons = CreateCategoryButtons(out ids);

var GeoCard = new HeroCard(text: "Are you interested in searching through the file? Please select the Category you would like to refine Credentials for:")
{
    Buttons = cardButtons
};

replyMessage.Attachments.Add(GeoCard.ToAttachment());
replyMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<List<string>>("ids", ids);
await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
context.Wait(CategoryValidate);
//  context.Wait(optionCategoryValidate);
context.Done(true);
```

Comment: The code above is calling context.Wait just before context.Done.  If you wish for the next message from the user to resume at CategoryValidate, then do not call context.Done immediately afterwards.  context.Done will end the current dialog.

Comment: yes, it was commented actually, must have missed while editing the question

Comment: CategoryValidate is where the code will resume after the user's button choice.  Is that not working as expected? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you just trying to have the bot message 'YOU HAVE SELECTED XYZ' to the user after they pressed one of the buttons on the card?

Comment: yes, instead of showing the button value as if the user has typed it, I want to show a message from the bot 'YOU HAVE SELECTED XYZ'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the user to select an item after you sent the card, you can add a flag to the card actions' value attribute to notify the bot when the user has made a selection and respond to the user in the `onTurnAsync` method with their choice. I would recommend setting the value for the card actions to something like 'selected: `option`' and have that value sent as a postBack so the flag remains hidden to the user. Then when the `onTurnAsync` method is called and the activity is a message, you can check the message for your flag send an activity to the user with their choice. See the code snippet below.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Bot Code - C#**

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message) {

            // Check for selected flag
            if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Split(' ')[0] == "selected:") {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You {turnContext.Activity.Text}");
            } else {
                var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();

                reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                reply.Attachments.Add(GetHeroCard().ToAttachment());

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    private static HeroCard GetHeroCard()
    {
        var buttons = new List<CardAction>();
        buttons.Add(new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "operating group", value: "selected: operating group"));
        buttons.Add(new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "geo", value: "selected: geo"));
        buttons.Add(new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "technology", value: "selected: technology"));
        buttons.Add(new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "themes", value: "selected: themes"));


        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = "BotFramework Hero Card",
            Subtitle = "Microsoft Bot Framework",
            Images = new List<CardImage> {},
            Buttons = buttons,
        };

        return heroCard;
    }  
}
```

Note, the PostBack card action is not supported by every channel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it the same for v3 as well?

Comment: You should be able to do something similar in v3. You may have to use a waterfall dialog.